# Can someone help me fix this? Uncaught Error: Call to a member function exists()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress install on my site and I have a plugin the grabs user names from xenforo and imports them. Some users were already created on wordpress and now those users get this error if they try to sign in. Can someone help with the code this avoid this?

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function exists() on string in /home/xxx/public_html/blog/wp- 
includes/user.php on line 1365
clean_user_cache()
wp-includes/pluggable.php:2532
wp_set_password()
wp-content/plugins/xpress-forum-user-bridge/src/Filter/Authenticate.php:107
createUser()
wp-content/plugins/xpress-forum-user-bridge/src/Filter/Authenticate.php:94
authenticate()
wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:288
apply_filters()
wp-includes/plugin.php:206
apply_filters()
wp-includes/pluggable.php:539
wp_authenticate()
wp-includes/user.php:95
wp_signon()
wp-login.php:1187
```

Here is Authenticate.php from the plugin

```
    public static function authenticate($user, $login, $password)
    {
        if (get_option('xpress_lite_auth_with_xf', false) && $login && $password) {
            if ($user instanceof \WP_User) {
                return $user;
            }

            $apiClient = self::apiClient();

            if (!$apiClient) {
                return $user;
            }

            try {
                $xfUser = $apiClient->xf->auth->auth($login, $password);
            } catch (AbstractRequestException $e) {
                return $user;
            } catch (XFApiException $e) {
                return $user;
            }

            if ($xfUser) {
                return self::createUser($xfUser, $password, $login);
            }
        }

        return $user;
    }

    protected static function createUser($xfUser, $password, $login)
    {
        if ($xfUser->email) {
            $emailUser = get_user_by('email', $xfUser->email);

            if ($emailUser) {
                wp_set_password($emailUser->ID, $password);
                return $emailUser;
            }
        }

        $nameUser = get_user_by('login', $xfUser->username);
        if ($nameUser) {
            $newName = $xfUser->email;
        } else {
            $newName = $xfUser->username;
        }

        $userId = wp_create_user($newName, $password, $xfUser->email);
        return get_user_by('ID', $userId);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding FS_METHOD to wp-config.php solved the issues.

```
// worked
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

At first I went the route of FTP user, but locking the user access to a subdirectory broke again as the plugin kept requesting an absolute path no matter what. Even adding the paths in the config did not help in my case.

```
// updating paths did not help
define( 'FTP_BASE', '/path/to/wordpress/' );
define( 'FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/' );
define( 'FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/' );
define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org' );
define( 'FTP_SSL', false );
```

Comment: Thanks...it didn't work for me but I should probably be doing something more? Reinstalling it?

Comment: I think, needs to check on the live page because it needs to set on PHP and system/server settings.